# How to get the contravariant magnetic vector potential from the covariant vector potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry, potential, covariance

The vector potential is a divergence-free field. When it is subjected to the operation $\widetilde{F}=\nabla\vec{A}-\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)^T$, you get the covariant Faraday tensor. The contravariant Faraday tensor is given by $\underline{F}={\widetilde{g}}^{-1}\widetilde{F}{\widetilde{g}}^{-1}$. $\underline{F}$ shares some similar properties with $\widetilde{F}$. The free current can be found with the operation $\overleftarrow{J}=\mu_0^{-1}\nabla\cdot\underline{F}$, and an analog(if we’re thinking of the metric tensor as some kind of medium) of total current can be found with the operation $\vec{J}=\mu_0^{-1}\nabla\cdot\widetilde{F}$. If the divergence of either is taken again, the divergence of both currents will be 0($0=\nabla\cdot\vec{J}=\nabla\cdot\overleftarrow{J}$). The coordinate system is cartesian BTW. It stands to reason that a contravariant analog of $\vec{A}$ must exist where
$\underline{F}=\nabla\overleftarrow{A}-\left(\nabla\overleftarrow{A}\right)^T$. I’ve had great difficulty creating the formula for $\overleftarrow{A}$ as a function of $\vec{A}$ and $\widetilde{g}$ though. I know it must be possible, I’m just not sure how to get it. Any help is appreciated.

Useful relations are as follows:
$$\begin{matrix}\underline{M}={\widetilde{g}}^{-1}\widetilde{M}{\widetilde{g}}^{-1}&\left(\nabla\widetilde{M}\right)_{ijk}=\left(\frac{\partial M_{jk}}{\partial x_i}\right)&\left(\widetilde{M}\right)_i=\left[\begin{matrix}M_{i1}\\M_{i2}\\M_{i3}\\M_{i4}\\\end{matrix}\right]\\\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{g}\underline{M}\widetilde{g}&\nabla\cdot\widetilde{M}=\sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial\left(\widetilde{M}\right)_i}{\partial x_i}\right)&\nabla\cdot\left(f\widetilde{M}\right)=f\left(\nabla\cdot\widetilde{M}\right)+{\widetilde{M}}^T\nabla f\\\end{matrix}$$

Mxwell's equations in curved space are:
$$\begin{matrix}\vec{f}=\widetilde{F}\overleftarrow{J}&\widetilde{F}=\nabla\vec{A}-\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)^T\\\overleftarrow{J}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\nabla\cdot\underline{F}=\nabla\cdot\underline{\mathcal{D}}&\underline{\mathcal{D}}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\underline{F}\\\end{matrix}$$

Comment: To be clear, you’re looking for a vector field whose antiymmetrized gradient yields the fully contravariant Faraday tensor?

Comment: @J.Murray Precisely.